# Can't change background color out of TimedEvent();

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, time, timed-events

in my C# WPF project I have a timed Event. Inside the timedEvent I have multiple try catch function.
For example this:

```
try
            {
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("Dateien/DB/Box" + boxnumber + "_Abwesenheit.txt", true, Encoding.ASCII);
                sw.Write("\n" + WNR_KNR[1] + datetime);
                sw.Close();
                Rec_Background.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 0));
            }
            catch (Exception y)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception; " + y.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Abwesenheit automatisch Pause(1059)");
                absence = true;
            }
```

at Rec_background.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(255, 255, 0));

I got a Exception thrown:

> Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in WindowsBase.dll
> The thread 0xf4c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
> Exception; Der aufrufende Thread kann nicht auf dieses Objekt zugreifen, da sich das Objekt im Besitz eines anderen Threads befindet.
> The thread 0x4848 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

This exception is thrown multiple times in the timed Event. For example also when I try to write to text-file.
But this is only happening in the TimedEvent no where else.

Comment: That sounds like something going wrong in an `async/await`, `BackgroundWorker` or `DispatcherTimer`  process outside the code you were showing so far. As a wild guess, I'd suggest to try putting the root of the `async` process into a `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`

Comment: I saw this Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() akready. What is this exactly or how to use it?

Answer (score 0):

To put this  `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>`
before the Rec_background.... solved it.